alternative implementation of REST client in Quarkus
I have a rest client, defined as documentation suggests:
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "myservice")
@ApplicationScoped
@LookupIfProperty(name = "myapp.mode", stringValue = "real")
public interface MyAPI {
    @GET
    @Path("/api/xxx.json")
    XXX getXXX();
    ....
}

Additionally I have a mock implementation for this interface:
@RestClient
@ApplicationScoped
@LookupIfProperty(name = "myapp.mode", stringValue = "mock")
public class MockMyAPI implements MyAPI {
    XXX getXXX() {
       return ....;
    }
    ....
}


I use a runtime property that controls which implementation is to be used. All works well, although I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.
But when I run test - I'm getting the following exception:
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class a.b.c.MockMyAPI can not implement a.b.c.MyAPI, because it is not an interface (a.b.c.MyAPI is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @178c9eda)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:523)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:481)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
    at a.b.c.MockMyAPI_Bean.<init>(Unknown Source)

My question is - what is the right way to provide alternative implementations of REST client in quarkus? Or, in case I'm doing it right - what is wrong with my test?

Try it with @Fallback:
@Inject
@RestClient
MyAPI myAPI;

@Inject
@RestClient
MyMockAPI myMockAPI;

@Fallback(fallbackMethod="fallbackCall")
public String call() {
   return this.myApi.getXYZ();
}

private String fallbackCall() {
   Log.warn("calling fallback method");
   return this.myMockAPI.getXYZ();
}


It is not for testing. This mock is a part of system, and must be used when certain service is s not available.

@aav, I’ve updated the answer

they are different. Under normal conditions the api is exposed by some very complicated and expensive hardware. In case when this hardware is not available - we simulate certain aspects of it, so the rest of the system is able to operate. There are other use cases for it, i.e. demonstration setups, when sales people demonstrate how the software would work.

Of course I can make my own implementation of the REST service, and then access it with the client, by changing the url. But this would be a bit strange.

My understanding is, that all those java based IoC things, are about having different service implementations, sharing common interfaces. And assembling combinations of implementations at runtime. So the thing I want to have must be somehow trivial. The only issue is this "magic" when we provide only annotated interface, and no implementation. I guess the implementation is generated at the compilation time (or dynamically at runtime).

@aav, then in your case I think using Microprofile’s @ Fallback might be a better solution. And indeed, you must  not implement the REST interface. That’s automatically done. See this link for more info: https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-fault-tolerance#adding-resiliency-fallbacks
